# RESTful API help, confused with HTTP and XML responses

Tags: php, xml, api, http, rest

I am writing an API and have been reading tutorials etc from various sources.  I am a little confused regarding responses.  I have written a class that will send back a HTTP header response as well as an XML response.  Is this correct or should I be using one or the other and not both?  Also how to do I check the HTTP header response I send is correct?  Im using PHP.

I have used the following tool to check the HTTP response:
http://www.seoconsultants.com/tools/check-server-headers-tool/
which says the response is HTTP/1.1 200 OK.  However in my script I have set it as:
header(HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized);
Therefore which is correct?  How can I check properly?  Any ideas what is going wrong?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You have not accepted any of the answers... does any of them answer your question?!

Answer (score 2):

Redbot http://redbot.org/ will give a very thorough analysis of your HTTP response to ensure you are compliant with the HTTP spec.

You would be well advised to read some introductory material on the HTTP protocol.   It will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

In a restful service, you use the http methods get, put, post and delete, so the http header is there "included". The payload of such a method call can be formatted the way you like (it must be an existing mimetype!), so xml is possible, too! You have to divide between the response "metadata" and the response payload: the "metadata" is a http header, the payload is your xml string, so you have to send both! Otherwise, you would send an empty response :-)

In your request you have to define which data representation (in your case xml) should be used for the response. Have a look at this [image](http://www.christian-straube.de/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/restful2.jpg) (the left one ist restful).

But nevertheless it is a good idea to use a framework for this, like other answers say.

Comment: right OK, so I am correct in sending both HTTP and XML response.  How to I test the HTTP response as I am getting wrong results when I use the tool mentioned above.

Comment: static function errorResponse($status = 400, $body = '')  {  
$status_message = APIResponse::getStatusCodeMessage($status);
$status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' .$status_message;  
header("HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . $status_message");  
.....the method continues setting the XML response after the HTTP response.

Comment: basically this code is setting: header(HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized);

Comment: I think the best idea is to update your answer with your code. It is a little bit strange that you set 401 and 200 is sent to the consumer... beside this you use APIResponse -> Framework, PHP-native, ...? By updating your answer you an use syntax highlighting

Comment: I think I have found the issue but am unsure how to resolve it.  As I am using cURL to access the file, it is somehow not allowing me to set headers. When I access the same file directly through the browser wihtout cURL, its works.  Anyone therefore know how I get round this?

Comment: Again, please post your code! cURL has the option to use the headers, but without code we're not able to see if there's a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing this from scratch? if you are then use a common or popular framework as basis and concentrate to building your API methods and let the framework handle the delivery mechanism

http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/symfony2-rest/ and you can google for more samples

Comment: yes from scratch, Im almost finished and therefore do not want to switch to a framework.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Headers could be any you like - let the client handle them. Client can use them to find out if the operation (request) finished successfully or not, if the service is available and other common useful stuff. Headers are correct if they are either pre-defined by protocol and contain valid data or they are defined by you (no validations needed).

XML, JSON or any other response is the data you want to tell the client. It may contain details on errors, the results of performed actions and so on.

Comment: Yes but I need to ensure what I am sending is correct.  How do I do this?  This is my problem.  I do not know how to check.  So are you saying sending both HTTP and XML is ok? thanks

Comment: @LeeTee if you'll send `Something: blah-blah-blah` header, you can be sure it is correct. If you'll send `Something:` or `:blah-blah-blah` headers - **that** will be an error. So, you can check it with regexp: `$correct = preg_match('/^\w+:.+$/', $header);`. The `$correct` variable sill determine if the header format is OK.

Answer (score -1):

I don't suggest you mess with the HTTP header response. Keep it always set to 200 OK, and send back the needed information in the XML response.

That way, the client has to worry only about the XML response. In case there was an HTTP error, such as 403 Forbidden, it would mean this is on the system level (sever configuration) rather than on the application layer itself.

Comment: so using the PHP header() function to set the HTTP headers is incorrect?

Comment: It's not "incorrect". It is a matter of preference. But basically, all APIs I worked with usually return an error message via XML in case of an error, and HTTP status remains 200 OK. So basically, 200 OK can signify that the application was successfully reached and executed, regardless of the returned XML response.

HTTP header response indicates a transport message, not an application message.

Comment: @SiN What you are suggesting is a really bad idea.  Those response codes are there for a reason and should be used and respected. HTTP is an application protocol and is best used as such.

Comment: @Darrel if you get 403, how do you know whether this is security issue reaching the API or the API actually executed and returned an authentication failure to the user (e.g after checking the db)

Comment: @Darrel And I have to disagree, HTTP is a network protocol, not an application protocol

Comment: @sin Arguably, the client may have no business knowing who denied the request.  Having said that if the status code does not provide sufficient information, then the HTTP spec says you should use the ReasonPhrase part of the response header and also include a message body with additional details.  However, including the status code is essential to allow intermediary components on the network visibility into what is going on.

Comment: @sin From the abstract of RFC 2616 "The Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) is an *application-level* protocol for distributed, collaborative, hypermedia information systems."  Your misunderstanding is very common, but it really prevents people from using HTTP in the way it was intended.

Comment: ok, the book I have been reading on Restful services says to use HTTP responses hence, why I have done this, but also used XML to give the users a more in depth response.  However, what seems to be happeneing is all my HTTP respnses are comign back as 200 anyway even though I have set them to respond otherwise.  I used the header() PHP function to set the headers.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: @LeeTee Sorry, I don't use PHP.  Did you try using REDBOT?  Or if you are running Windows you can fiddler to make requests and see responses.